# Python PUT Request Fails with 400 Client Error After Multiple Successful Requests

Tags: python, api, http, exception, python-requests

I have a payload that is batched into separate dictionaries that are being sent to an API endpoint with multiple PUT requests. I have 15 requests that need to be sent, and I am able to successfully put about 10 requests and then the 11th request fails. The code is running the same with the same headers, and on the failed PUT request I immediately get this error when running the code.

Error

```
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:https:/xyz.xyz:443
Http Error: 400 Client Error: Bad Request for url: https://xyz.xyz
```

Headers

```
headers = {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
    "Accept": "*/*",
    "Connection": "keep-alive",
    "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.97 Safari/537.36",
    "x-api-key": API_KEY,
}
```

Request Code

```
try:
    response = requests.put(
        url=URL,
        headers=headers,
        json=data,
        timeout=600,
        verify=False
    )
    response.raise_for_status()
except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as errh:
    agent.notice_error()
    logging.info("Http Error: %s", errh)
except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError as errc:
    agent.notice_error()
    logging.info("Error Connecting: %s", errc)
except requests.exceptions.Timeout as errt:
    agent.notice_error()
    logging.info("Timeout Error: %s", errt)
except requests.exceptions.RequestException as err:
    agent.notice_error()
    logging.info("Exception: %s", err)
```

The response immediately raises a status of 400 on the 11th request.

I have tried batching the data into smaller chunks but still fails towards the end of the batched payload. I also took the failed request and made the PUT request through Postman so I know it is not the data.

What could be the issue with running this code? Why is it failing after a certain amount of requests but not the previous when all of the code is the same and the data is all formatted the same?

Comment: This most likely has nothing to do with your code. Try getting in touch with the maintainers of the API you're calling, or perhaps there is a more meaningful message returned with the 400 response payload.

Comment: It could be rate limiting, and the server is incorrectly returning 400 instead of 429. See if the API docs mention anything about rate limits, check the headers and body of the error response, and maybe try adding some delays in between requests. Or after an error, retry and delay a few times with backoff. [urllib3.util.Retry](https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/urllib3.util.html) can help there.